# How to debug "expected android.widget.TextView but found java.lang.string" in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

Can someone please take a look at my code? I am trying to build this app for a personal school project. I am new to android studio. I have put together a simple app where you display the spaces available in a parking lot.

But now I am trying to open a second activity screen when I click on one of the lots in the listView screen. I got this error and have no way of solving it.

```
**MainActivity.java**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout         
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lotName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lotSpaces"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lotName"/>

</RelativeLayout>

**SingleLotView.java**

package com.example.sahan.smartpark;

/**
* Created by Sahan on 2015-10-14.
*/
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleLotView extends Activity{

//declare variables
TextView lotName;
TextView lotSpaces;

String[] lot_name;
String[] lot_spaces;
int position;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.singlelotview);
    // Retrieve data from MainActivity on listview item click
    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Get the listview item click position
    position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
    // Get the list of rank
   lotName = i.getStringArrayExtra("lotName");
    // Get the list of country
   lotSpaces = i.getStringArrayExtra("lotSpaces");
    // Get the list of population

    // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
    lotName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.move_title);
    lotSpaces = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.move_title);

    // Load the text into the TextViews followed by the position
    lotName.setText(lot_name[position]);
    lotSpaces.setText(lot_spaces[position]);

}
}

**MoveAdapter.java**

package com.example.sahan.smartpark;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by Sahan on 2015-10-12.
*/
public class MoveAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
List list=new ArrayList();

public MoveAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}


static class DataHandler
{
    ImageView poster;
    TextView name;
    TextView spaces;
}
public void add(Object object){
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}
public int getCount(){
    return this.list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row=convertView;
    DataHandler handler;

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout,parent,false);
        handler=new DataHandler();
        handler.poster=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.move_poster);
        handler.name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.move_title);
        handler.spaces=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.move_rating);
        row.setTag(handler);
    }
    else {

        handler=(DataHandler)row.getTag();
    }
    MoveDataProvider dataProvider;

    dataProvider=(MoveDataProvider)this.getItem(position);
    handler.poster.setImageResource
         (dataProvider.getMove_poster_resource());
    handler.name.setText(dataProvider.getLot_name());
    handler.spaces.setText(dataProvider.getLot_spaces());
    return row;




}
}

**SingleToView.xml**
package com.example.sahan.smartpark;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by Sahan on 2015-10-12.
*/
public class MoveAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
List list=new ArrayList();

public MoveAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}


static class DataHandler
{
    ImageView poster;
    TextView name;
    TextView spaces;
}
public void add(Object object){
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}
public int getCount(){
    return this.list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row=convertView;
    DataHandler handler;

    if(convertView==null)
    {

        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout,parent,false);
        handler=new DataHandler();
        handler.poster=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.move_poster);
        handler.name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.move_title);
        handler.spaces=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.move_rating);
        row.setTag(handler);
    }
    else {

        handler=(DataHandler)row.getTag();
    }
    MoveDataProvider dataProvider;

    dataProvider=(MoveDataProvider)this.getItem(position);

    handler.poster.setImageResource
    (dataProvider.getMove_poster_resource());

    handler.name.setText(dataProvider.getLot_name());
    handler.spaces.setText(dataProvider.getLot_spaces());
    return row;

}
}

**strings.xml**

<resources>
<string name="app_name">SmartPark</string>

<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string-array name="lot_name">
    <item>  Parking Lot A</item>
    <item>  Parking Lot B</item>

</string-array>

<string-array name="lot_spaces">
    <item>Available:  225</item>
    <item>Available:  107</item>

</string-array>

</resources>
```

The error I get is on my SingleLotView.java code:

> Incompatible types - expected android.widget.TextView  but found java.lang.string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lotName = i.getStringArrayExtra("lotName");
```

should be:

```
lot_name = i.getStringArrayExtra("lotName");
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick and it was actually a careless mistake on my end. But I have gotten another error and am wondering if you can take a look at it if you don't mind. Thanks a bunch. This is the error I get: AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activityComponentInfo{com.example.sahan.smartpark/com.example.sahan.smartpark.SingleLotView}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array

Comment: I'd suggest learning to use a debugger and stepping through the code to see what is causing the NPE (NullPointerException).  Also check the name of the resource you are looking up.